# ORA-00904: "PARAMETER": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I get a error, when I execute my SQL:

> select bd.name aaa,
>           sum(p.nassistnum) HH,sum(case when p.vbdef4='~' then '0' else p.vbdef4 end) KK
>           from ic_purchasein_b p,bd_marbasclass bd,bd_material_v m ,ic_purchasein_h h
>           where   m.pk_source=p.cmaterialvid
>           and p.cgeneralhid= h.cgeneralhid
>           and  bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4)
>           and m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'
>           and h.vdef8='1001A2100000000FUD01'
>           and h.ctrantypeid='1001A210000000002UXJ'
>           and h.pk_org in (parameter('param3'))
>                           and substr(h.dbilldate,1,10) >= parameter('param1')
>                           and substr(h.dbilldate,1,10) <= parameter('param2')
>           group by bd.name) group by aaa
>   [Err] ORA-00904: "PARAMETER": invalid identifier

My SQL is:

```
select DISTINCT aaa,sum(HH) sum1,sum(KK) sum2 from                       
   (   select bd.name aaa,
        sum(p.nassistnum) HH,sum(case when p.vbdef4='~' then '0' else p.vbdef4 end) KK 
        from ic_purchasein_b p,bd_marbasclass bd,bd_material_v m ,ic_purchasein_h h
        where   m.pk_source=p.cmaterialvid
        and p.cgeneralhid= h.cgeneralhid 
        and  bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4) 
        and m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'
        and h.vdef8='~'
        and (h.ctrantypeid='1001A210000000002UXJ' or h.ctrantypeid='1001A210000000002UW7' or h.ctrantypeid='1001A210000000002UY9')
        and h.pk_org in (parameter('param3'))
                        and substr(h.dbilldate,1,10) >= parameter('param1')
                        and substr(h.dbilldate,1,10) <= parameter('param2')    
        group by bd.name
  UNION      
    select bd.name aaa,
        sum(p.nassistnum) HH,sum(case when p.vbdef4='~' then '0' else p.vbdef4 end) KK 
        from ic_purchasein_b p,bd_marbasclass bd,bd_material_v m ,ic_purchasein_h h
        where   m.pk_source=p.cmaterialvid
        and p.cgeneralhid= h.cgeneralhid 
        and  bd.code=substr(m.code,0,4) 
        and m.creator='1001A210000000000IIQ'
        and h.vdef8='1001A2100000000FUD01'
        and h.ctrantypeid='1001A210000000002UXJ'
        and h.pk_org in (parameter('param3'))
                        and substr(h.dbilldate,1,10) >= parameter('param1')
                        and substr(h.dbilldate,1,10) <= parameter('param2') 
        group by bd.name) group by aaa
```

But I don't know where is the error, why my PARAMETER is invalid identifier?

Comment: Is `parameter` a function you've written? It isn't a buolt-in one.

Comment: @Alex Poole, I finally find the `parapeter` method is self-create method in a custom environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ORA-00904 string: invalid identifier Cause: The column name entered is
>   either missing or invalid.
>
> Action: Enter a valid column name. A valid column name must begin with
>   a letter, be less than or equal to 30 characters, and consist of only
>   alphanumeric characters and the special characters $, _, and #. If it
>   contains other characters, then it must be enclosed in double
>   quotation marks. It may not be a reserved word.

You might simply have to re-check your column names and functions in the query.

[Oracle's manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm)

And definitely take @Alex Poole's comment into account.